# How to refer to components located in a different ui:include

Tags: jsf-2

On a facelet composed with different `ui:include`, what would be the best way to refer to a component located in `ui:composition` 2 from `ui:composition` 1?

Example:

fileA.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:commandButton value="OK" action="#{bean.foo}" update=":componentToUpdate"/>
</ui:composition>
```

fileB.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:panel id="componentToUpdate">
        // ...
    </p:panel>
</ui:composition>
```

Here, I'm "hardcoding" the id, "componentToUpdate". I thought of using a parameter:

```
<ui:include src="fileA.xhtml" >
    <ui:param name="myParam" value="myId"/>
</ui:include>
```

fileB.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:panel id="#{myId}">
        // ...
    </p:panel>
</ui:composition>
```

Would it be interesting to have a bean that maintains all of these ids?

Hope I'm clear enough, thanks.